# Is there a shorthand for RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, xaml-binding

Specifying the templated parent as the source for a binding in a templated control seems common but irritatingly verbose. Is there a shorthand way of doing this?

Some sort of prefix on the path would seem more reasonable. e.g.

```
{Binding ^Title}
```

or something like that, instead of

```
{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [TemplateBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/templatebinding-markup-extension):

```
{TemplateBinding Title}
```

Note however that

> The types used as the value for the source property and the target
>   property must match. There's no opportunity to introduce a converter
>   when you're using TemplateBinding. Failing to match values results in
>   an error when parsing the XAML. If you need a converter you can use
>   the verbose syntax for a template binding such as: `{Binding
>   RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter="..." ...}`

and, probably more important, the second sentence here:

> A TemplateBinding is always a one-way binding. Both properties
>   involved must be dependency properties.

Comment: You would think that, wouldn't you? Tried it, but I get an exception along the lines of "Property Title not found on object of class Thing". But it very much does have that property.

Comment: "Both properties involved must be dependency properties." That's probably it. The target is the Text property of a TextBlock, which isn't a dependency property.

Comment: Thanks for figuring out why TemplateBinding doesn't work for me. I need to learn to read the docs more carefully... I guess this didn't actually answer my original question though, i.e. is there a shorthand equivalent to the verbose regular {Binding} markup. I guess the answer is "No" though!

Comment: I was wondering if you would go for a new answer that was just "No." :-)